# Is there such a jQuery selector that states 'all matched items except $(this)?

Tags: jquery

here is a line of code that works except that it selects the item that was clicked on.
i want to select all items except what was clicked on.

```
$('ul.open').removeClass('open').addClass('close').slideUp();
```

my pseudo code something like this…

```
$('ul.open:not(' + $(this))).addClass('close').removeClass('open').slideUp();
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Sounds like you're maybe building an accordion; there's already something in the UI library, if that's what you're after: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('ul.open').not(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close').slideUp();
```